# Order sum and order value is not fetching properly in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables.

table_orders

```
order_id
customer_id
order_datetime
order_payment_type
order_delivery_date
delivery_time_slot
```

table_order_details

```
order_id
product_id
varient_id
quantity
product_mrp
product_sell_price
product_name
```

table_order_status

```
order_id
status_id
status_datetime
```

table_order_status_values

```
value_id
value_desc
```

I want to get order id, order amount, order date, order quantity, order time, value_desc.

I am running this query.

```
SELECT oo.order_id, oo.amount, oo.date, oo.quantity, oo.time, value_desc
FROM 
(
     SELECT s.order_id,  SUM(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) as amount, 
       DATE_FORMAT(o.order_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') as date, SUM(OD.quantity) 
       as quantity, TIME(o.order_datetime) as time, MAX( status_id ) as laststatus
     FROM table_orders o
     INNER JOIN table_order_details AS OD ON o.order_id = OD.order_id
     INNER JOIN table_order_status s ON s.order_id = o.order_id
     GROUP BY o.order_id
)oo

INNER JOIN table_order_status_values ON value_id = laststatus

order by order_id DESC
```

sample Data:

Table_orders

```
1 1 2015:12:12:19:42:47 1 2015:12:14 1
```

table_order_details

```
1 12 3 1 21.00 20.00 abcd
1 13 2 2 100.00 90.00 efgh
```

table_order_status

```
1 1 2015:12:12:19:42:47
1 2 2015:12:12:20:42:47
```

table_order_status_values

```
1 NEW ORDER
2 CONFIRM
3 Delivered
```

With the above query Output is:

```
1 400.00 12:12:2015 6 19:42:47 CONFIRM
```

But expected output is:

```
1 200.00 12:12:2015 3 19:42:47 CONFIRM
```

I am getting order amount and order quantity values twice (or thrice) based on number of status for given order.

How to correct this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an example output? It's likely to be caused by the join on `table_order_status`. Perhaps you only need to get the latest status, not all the intermediary values

Comment: @AlexTartan, I got your point. But i am using MAX(status_id) to get last status for that order.

Comment: Although not as correct, you *could* use `SELECT distinct oo.order_id ...`. Or try to join on a subselect of `table_order_status` already grouped by order_id, instead of the entire table. If you manage to set up an SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) I could take a look

Comment: What's with `SUM(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) as amount` instead of just `OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity as amount`?

Answer (score 2):

You problem is in this part:

```
SELECT s.order_id,  SUM(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) as amount, 
       DATE_FORMAT(o.order_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') as date, SUM(OD.quantity) 
       as quantity, TIME(o.order_datetime) as time, MAX( status_id ) as laststatus
     FROM table_orders o
     INNER JOIN table_order_details AS OD ON o.order_id = OD.order_id
     INNER JOIN table_order_status s ON s.order_id = o.order_id
     GROUP BY o.order_id
```

The sum doesn't returns the current value because it get multiplied with each join.

You can solve this be getting this with a select instead of using just the columns.

```
(SELECT SUM(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) FROM table_order_details as OD WHERE OD.order_id=o.order_id)  as amount
```

And for the quantity use:

```
(SELECT SUM(OD.quantity)  FROM table_order_details as OD WHERE OD.order_id=s.order_id) as quantity,
```

So the final query will be:

```
SELECT oo.order_id, oo.amount, oo.date, oo.quantity, oo.time, value_desc
FROM 
(
       SELECT 
       s.order_id,  
       (SELECT SUM(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) FROM table_order_details as OD WHERE OD.order_id=s.order_id) as amount, 
       DATE_FORMAT(o.order_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') as date,
       (SELECT SUM(OD.quantity)  FROM table_order_details as OD WHERE OD.order_id=s.order_id) as quantity, 
       TIME(o.order_datetime) as time, MAX( status_id ) as laststatus
     FROM table_orders o
     INNER JOIN table_order_status s ON s.order_id = o.order_id
     GROUP BY o.order_id
)oo

INNER JOIN table_order_status_values ON value_id = laststatus

order by order_id DESC
```

And it will output:

```
1 200 12/12/2015 3 19:42:47 CONFIRIM
```

**edit** - i have also removed the

```
INNER JOIN table_order_details AS OD ON o.order_id = OD.order_id
```

No need for it to be joined in this query

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your SQL is not valid, MySQL ignore this invlaid SQL but the result will not be what you expected.

```
SELECT o.order_id,
    oo.amt,
    DATE_FORMAT(o.order_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') date,
    oo.qty, 
    TIME(o.order_datetime) time,
    osv.value_desc  
FROM table_orders o, table_order_status_values osv, (
    SELECT order_id, sum(quantity) qty, sum(product_sell_price*quantity) amt
    FROM table_order_details
    GROUP BY 1
) AS oo, (
    SELECT order_id, max(status_id) last_status
    FROM table_order_status
    GROUP BY 1
) AS os
WHERE o.order_id = os.order_id AND os.last_status = osv.status_id
AND o.order_id = oo.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should focus first subselect on getting all the order information except that status and then join in the status information.

That might look like this:

```
SELECT
    order_with_status.order_id AS order_id,
    order_with_status.amount AS amount,
    order_with_status.`date` AS `date`,
    order_with_status.quantity AS quantity,
    order_with_status.`time` AS `time`,
    tosv.value_description AS current_status       
FROM (
    /* Add maximum order status value to result set */
    SELECT
        order.order_id AS order_id,
        order.amount AS amount,
        order.`date` AS `date`,
        order.quantity AS quantity,
        order.`time` AS `time`,
        MAX(tos.status) AS current_status_id
    FROM (
        /* Get rolled-up order information as start to result set */
        SELECT
            o.order_id AS order_id,
            SUM(od.product_sell_price * od.quantity) AS amount,
            DATE_FORMAT(o.order_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') AS `date`,
            SUM(od.quantity) AS `quantity`,
            TIME(o.order_datetime) AS `time`
        FROM table_orders AS o
        INNER JOIN table_order_details AS od
            ON o.order_id = od.order_id
        GROUP BY o.order_id
    ) as order
    INNER JOIN table_order_status AS tos
        ON order.order_id = tos.order_id
) as order_with_status
INNER JOIN table_order_status_values AS tosv
    ON order_with_status.current_status_id = tosv.value_id

ORDER BY order_with_status.order_id DESC
```

Note that your schema itself makes this a very complex query, that would likely not perform very well if you need to do this query regularly in your system.  If you made the simple change to move an order status id field into the order table, you could simplify this greatly (relegating your table_order_status table to simply being a audit history of status changes not used at all in this type of query). This makes logical sense in that there doesn't seem to be a need to work with the change history of an order when trying to simply get current order data.

In this case the query could be as simple as

```
SELECT
    o.order_id AS order_id,
    tosv.value_description AS current_status,
    SUM(od.product_sell_price * od.quantity) AS amount,
    DATE_FORMAT(o.order_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') AS `date`,
    SUM(od.quantity) AS quantity,
    TIME(o.order_datetime) AS `time`
FROM table_orders AS o
INNER JOIN table_order_status_values AS tosv
    ON o.order_status_id = tosv.value_id
INNER JOIN table_order_details AS od
    ON o.order_id = od.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC
```

You could simplify this further if you wanted to put the status description in the order table as opposed to the id (this would eliminate an extra table join to get the description).

Now whether this apparent de-normalization makes sense for your application would largely be determined by the use cases with the application.  If for example, you don't access the audit data much, or only need to present this data within the context of a single order, this may make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The sub-query you have used without group by and sum/max:

```
SELECT s.order_id,  OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity as amount, 
       DATE_FORMAT(o.order_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') as date, OD.quantity 
       as quantity, TIME(o.order_datetime) as time, status_id as laststatus
     FROM table_orders o
     INNER JOIN table_order_details AS OD ON o.order_id = OD.order_id
     INNER JOIN table_order_status s ON s.order_id = o.order_id
```

would have resulted in:

```
1 20*1 2015:12:12 1 19:42:47 1
1 20*1 2015:12:12 1 19:42:47 2
1 90*2 2015:12:12 2 19:42:47 1
1 90*2 2015:12:12 2 19:42:47 2
```

By adding SUM/MAX and group by it gives the output you have given in the question:

```
1 400.00 12:12:2015 6 19:42:47 2
```

Which is correct as per the query you have written. The solution is that you should get the MAX(status_id) separately.
So use the following query:

```
SELECT oo.order_id, oo.amount, oo.date, oo.quantity, oo.time, value_desc
FROM 
(
    SELECT s.order_id,  SUM(OD.product_sell_price * OD.quantity) as amount, 
       DATE_FORMAT(o.order_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') as date, SUM(OD.quantity) 
       as quantity, TIME(o.order_datetime) as time, MAX(select MAX( status_id ) from table_order_status ts where ts.order_id = o.order_id group by ts.order_id) as laststatus
     FROM table_orders o
     INNER JOIN table_order_details AS OD ON o.order_id = OD.order_id
     GROUP BY o.order_id
)oo

INNER JOIN table_order_status_values ON value_id = laststatus

order by order_id DESC
```

It will use the rows:

```
1 20*1 2015:12:12 1 19:42:47 2
1 90*2 2015:12:12 2 19:42:47 2
```

Giving the expected output:

```
1 200 2015:12:12 319:42:47 2
```